TypeError: quill_placeholder_module__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_42__ is not a function
I am using shared library package code in host then I am getting this quill-placehoolder error in host
main.ts:2  TypeError: quill_placeholder_module__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_42__ is not a function
    at 10517 
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)
    at sharing:61:1
    at __webpack_require__.m.<computed> (consumes:362:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)
    at 17876 
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)
    at 55041 (src_bootstrap_ts.js:20:89)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)
    at 25533 (toastr.component.ts:9:25)

In shared library I have component where I am importing it and registering it to quill:
import { QuillEditorComponent as NgxQuillEditorComponent, QuillModules, QuillToolbarConfig } from 'ngx-quill';
import Quill from 'quill';
import QuillImageDropAndPaste from 'quill-image-drop-and-paste';
import QuillMention from 'quill-mention';
import PlaceholderModule from 'quill-placeholder-module';

Quill.register('modules/placeholder', PlaceholderModule(Quill, {
    className: 'ql-placeholder-content',  // default
}));

How can I resolve this error?
I tried removing node modules and re-install it but it did not work.
